# How to display author name in joomla search results

Tags: com-search

I wonder if it is possible to display author name or created_by or created_by_alias in com_search results page.

In components/com_search/views/search/tmpl/default_results.php,
this obviously wouldn't work :

```
    ....
<dd>
        <?php echo $result->created_by_alias; ?>
    </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do this with the default Search component without modifying the search plugin database query. This is considered a core hack, therefore not recommended.

Instead I'd suggest using Smart Search:

1. Go to **Plugins** >> **Smart Search**, then enable it.
2. Go to **Modules** >> **Smart Search**. Enable and assign to a page.
3. Go to **Components** >> **Smart Search** >> **Index**.

---

Now that the initial steps are done, you should create a [Template Override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for the following file:

> components\com_finder\views\search\tmpl\default_result.php

Once done, open the template override file:

> templates\YOUR_TEMPLATE\html\com_finder\search\default_result.php

In here, you need to add the following code which will display the author:

```
<?php echo $this->result->author; ?>
```

Hope this helps